# Can't access existing MonetDB with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, monetdb, monetdblite

I created a MonetDBLite database yesterday, populated it, and was accessing it with `dplyr`, however this morning I don't seem able to use `dplyr`.

Here's my connection:

```
statcast_db <- MonetDBLite::src_monetdblite("/Users/williampetti/statcast_database/statcast_db_Monet", create = FALSE)
```

And here's a simple query for the `statcast_17` table:

```
statcast_db %>% 
    tbl("statcast_17") %>% 
    select(game_date) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    collect() %>% 
    tail(n = 1)
```

Yesterday, this worked fine. This morning, I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("db_query_fields") : 
  no applicable method for 'db_query_fields' applied to an object of class "MonetDBEmbeddedConnection"
```

If I use a simple `dbGetQuery` call, however, it works fine:

```
> dbGetQuery(statcast_db$con, "SELECT game_date FROM statcast_17 ORDER BY game_date DESC LIMIT 1")
   game_date
1 2017-04-29
```

Here's my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xml2_1.1.1        baseballr_0.3.1   RSQLite_1.0.0     pacman_0.4.1     
 [5] dplyr_0.5.0       purrr_0.2.2       readr_1.0.0       tidyr_0.6.0      
 [9] tibble_1.2        ggplot2_2.2.1     tidyverse_1.0.0   magrittr_1.5     
[13] MonetDBLite_0.3.1 RMySQL_0.10.9     DBI_0.5-1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_3.3.1       lattice_0.20-33     colorspace_1.2-6   
 [4] htmltools_0.3.5     mgcv_1.8-12         chron_2.3-47       
 [7] XML_3.98-1.6        survival_2.40-1     hexbin_1.27.1      
[10] foreign_0.8-66      RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4         
[13] stringr_1.2.0       munsell_0.4.3       gtable_0.2.0       
[16] rvest_0.3.2         XML2R_0.0.6         codetools_0.2-14   
[19] latticeExtra_0.6-28 knitr_1.14          reldist_1.6-6      
[22] htmlTable_1.7       Rcpp_0.12.9         acepack_1.4.1      
[25] scales_0.4.1        pitchRx_1.8.2       Hmisc_4.0-0        
[28] gridExtra_2.2.1     digest_0.6.11       stringi_1.1.3      
[31] grid_3.3.1          tools_3.3.1         bitops_1.0-6       
[34] lazyeval_0.2.0      RCurl_1.95-4.8      Formula_1.2-1      
[37] cluster_2.0.4       MASS_7.3-45         Matrix_1.2-6       
[40] data.table_1.9.6    lubridate_1.6.0     httr_1.2.1         
[43] assertthat_0.1      R6_2.1.3            rpart_4.1-10       
[46] nnet_7.3-12         nlme_3.1-128
```

Comment: Please try with the dev version of MonetDBLite from Github. Dplyr recently made some changes.

Comment: When I try to install the dev version I get this `Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build MonetDBLite`. Other dev versions of packages install fine for me with `devtools::install_github`.

Comment: You might need to install xcode command line tools on OSX for this since MonetDBLite contains lots of C code

Comment: Still running into the same problem. Updated to dev version of `MoneyDBLite`, as well as `dbplyr` and `dplyr`. Also now running `R` 3.4.

Comment: Could you perhaps make a simple reproducible example with the mtcars table please? I'd like to turn this into a test case.

Comment: Still no luck with dev versions of DBI, MonetDBLite, dbplyr & dplyr?

Comment: No, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, so used basic SQL query instead of dplyr at this point.

Comment: I AM having the same issues. Any solution?

Comment: So, I don't know if this is the issue, but I am attaching packages in this order and it's allowing me to use `dplyr` to query my database: `MonetDBLite`, `DBI`, `tidyverse`. When I switch the order it gives me the same old error.

Comment: Is this somehow running in RStudio?

Comment: Yes, although I believe I had the same issue outside of RStudio

Answer (score 0):

I just replied to a similar question this morning after figuring out that the order in which you load `MonetDBLite` matters. I came across this question trying to figure out why it does matter. I was having the same type of `Error in UseMethod` problems as BillPetti. Making sure `MonetDBLite` loads after `dplyr` and `dbplyr` has resolved the issue for me. Here's the link to that other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307673/3705612

Comment: Just wanted to acknowledge that I hadn't seen @BillPetti's last comment (dated 6-Apr-2018) when offering my answer. And now I'm wondering if it's really the order of package loading that is causing the error or whether instead if it's the pre-existing "src_monetdb" object in the workspace when starting the R session. With a clean workspace I can load MonetDBLite before `dplyr` and `dbplyr` and have it work.